# Should I discuss pay raise at the same time I ask for a promotion?

Tags: negotiation, promotion

I have been working at my company for about a year. During the performance review last year, my manager would like to me to take a lead on multiple high profile projects to build my track records. Starting from Jan, I have successfully delivered 3 most important products on time and received positive feedback from the customers.

Most people (everyone except me) with the same job grade only take a lead on one product while I am leading 4. From the actual work, I have been doing the job of the next job grade and I plan to discuss with my manager about a promotion and pay raise.

I already asked him to have a meeting to discuss this next week. I have everything I needed but there are one thing I am not sure which is whether I should discuss pay raise in this meeting.

I personally think it is better to make my expectation clear from the start and discuss a promotion and pay raise in this meeting. However, a few websites suggested that I should discuss the promotion first. Once I get promoted then I can discuss the number.

What are the pros and cons of each option? How should I plan the discuss for a pay raise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: @gnat No, that does not answer my question. I am looking for suggestions on how I should handle an 'ask for a promotion' meeting and whether it's a good idea to discuss the number. Thank you for the link though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should discuss the pay rise with the promotion, and make sure that it is understood that they are a single package.

It sounds like you're already taking on more responsibility than your job role and pay grade. I'm sure your company would be delighted for you to agree to take on even more, without even having to discuss paying you accordingly until afterwards (when they might simply say "no").